# Removed non-ASCII values and then lowering text is giving error

Tags: r, data-cleaning, stringi

I have a big data set which I cleaned up and found that one of the fields has value like

```
"My son is turning into a monster \xf0\u009f\u0098\u0092"
```

I am not able to create this simple data as it gives the below mentioned error

```
a <- c('My son is turning into a monster \xf0\u009f\u0098\u0092')
```

> Error: mixing Unicode and octal/hex escapes in a string is not allowed

Now suppose I have this value in my variable and want to remove all non-ascii characters like

```
library(stringi)
b <- stri_trans_general(a, "latin-ascii")
```

and now want to converted text in the lower format

```
tolower(b)
```

I am getting below mentioned error

> Error in tolower(b) :    invalid input 'My son is turning into a
>   monster ðŸ˜’' in 'utf8towcs'

Can someone please help me to understand the issue

Comment: what is `a` (as it couldn't be created with the call giving error)?

Comment: I also not able to create it manually, its part of a big text and I just assigned values like a <- cleanData[2119]

Comment: Please use `dput(a)` and copy the result into your question

Comment: thanks, i use dput and update the question

Comment: after using dput, it convert my text to 'My son is turning into a monster <f0><U+009F><U+0098><U+0092>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all non-ASCII characters you can use regex. `[\x00-\x7F]` is the set of all non-ASCII characters, so we can replace every occurrence with nothing.  However, R doesn't like `\x00` because it's the null character, so I had to modify the series to be `[\x01-\x7F]`

```
a <- c('My son is turning into a monster \u009f\u0098\u0092')
#> [1] "My son is turning into a monster \u009f\u0098\u0092"
tolower(gsub('[^\x01-\x7F]+','',a))
#> [1] "my son is turning into a monster "
```

or, with the octal codes

```
a <- c('My son is turning into a monster \xf0')
#> [1] "My son is turning into a monster ð"
tolower(gsub('[^\x01-\x7F]+','',a))
#> [1] "my son is turning into a monster "
```

Comment: thanks, its working for me ...I am not sure how my text will become mix of octal and other characters

Comment: It looks like you have comments from the web - it's probably a mix of emoji and emoji-like characters that are poorly converted by R.

Comment: true, its from twitter so kind of mixture

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iconv` to remove non-ASCII characters:

```
a <- c('My son is turning into a monster \xf0\x9f\x98\x92')
a
[1] "My son is turning into a monster ðŸ˜’"
iconv(a,to="ASCII",sub="")
[1] "My son is turning into a monster "
```

Comment: thanks its working for me, I was not sure how my text become mixture of octal and normal text